# Count rows without issuing a separate count

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, count

I currently have two separate queries:

1) returns the actual resultset based on various filters.

```
select a, b, c from TableA
where x = 123
and y = 'ABC'
and z = 999
```

2) displays the total number of rows.

```
select count(*) from TableA
where x = 123
and y = 'ABC'
and z = 999
```

So in short I am running same query twice. The queries I have put above as examples are much simpler than what I have with multiple joins and many filters.

Is there a better way of achieving the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select a, b, c, count(*) over() as total
from dbo.TableA
where x = 123
and y = 'ABC'
and z = 999;
```

Comment: thanks Aaron, firstly for editing my post (making it more readable) and secondly for your answer; and yes, it did work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just return the count as a column in your first query?

e.g.

```
select a, b, c, count(*) as total from TableA
where x = 123
and y = 'ABC'
and z = 999
```

This would avoid running it twice

Comment: You must have `GROUP BY` to make `COUNT()`.

Comment: ...and a GROUP BY would change the output.

Comment: @douga, Group By would have solved the issue of getting the count but my select part would have got affected by it. thanks for your help though.

Comment: That'll learn me for posting a sample! I meant it perhaps more as a conceptual change, can you re-write the first query to include the count you want from the second?
I'm guessing if you need to bind it to two controls you may end up returning this data and then binding to it in memory rather than direct to data sources, but it's probably the way to go.
Otherwise you could perhaps just return the first query to memory and count it in there via something like linq?